# R interface to imgflip API (https://api.imgflip.com/). Always ends in with the failure "No texts supplied"

Tags: r, api

A simple post using the `httr` package always ends with an error?

```
# Post a random meme and print its url
res <- httr::POST(
  url = "https://api.imgflip.com/caption_image",
  body = list(
    template_id = "61579",
    username =  "<my-username>",
    password =  "<my-password>",
    text0 = "abc",
    text1 = "def",
    font = "impact",
    max_font_size = "50"
  ),
  httr::verbose(),
  encode = "json"
)
httr::content(res, "text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure how to do it in R, but I tried using `postman` and sending the request as `JSON` do not work you have to send it as a `form-data`:
[image]

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! Switching from `encode = "json"` to `encode = "form"` did the trick.