# How to implement a post method for Imgflip API

Tags: java, android, api

I am trying to create an app on android studio and im new to this IDE and language. I managed to implement the GET method for Imflip api, but im stuck on the POST method. I would like to return an Meme with a caption added by the user.

Im using Android Studio 3.4.1. I've tried the code attached. For testing purposes, i've hardcoded the username, password, and two captions. Also, when i call POST() I pass the id 61579 as a parameter. I've tried finding he value for the response but it says that its "200"...

What i need is a url for the created meme.

Hope anyone can help.
Thanks in Advance.

```
private void POST(String memeID) {
    try {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String URL = "https://api.imgflip.com/caption_image";
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("template_id", memeID);
        jsonBody.put("username", "Meme_Genie");
        jsonBody.put("password", "Password");
        jsonBody.put("text0", "Hello");
        jsonBody.put("text1", "World");
        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I was also facing similar problem with this API. The error message was always '"No texts specified. Remember, API request params are http parameters not JSON.' though status code was '200'. The reason is, sending JSON won't work. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032202/r-interface-to-imgflip-api-https-api-imgflip-com-always-ends-in-with-the-f . It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from encode = `"json"` to encode = `"form"`

Or switching your body to `BodySerializationMethod.UrlEncoded` will work